# Wizz-air Discount Club companion travelling alone without the holder

Tags: air-travel, check-in, wizz-air

i want to ask if it is possible to book a ticket for me (discount holder) and one other person. They check in for the flight, I do not (i miss the flight) do they still get the discount? Can they board without me being there? The booking is for both people, but only one will fly.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no problems. Every passenger gets a personal boarding card and can take the flight.
And also the price your ticket will be higher than the discount for the second passenger, so the airline will not lose money.

[The Website of WizzAir](https://corporate.wizzair.com/en-GB/travel_services/WECTermsandC) states:

> The Wizz Discount Club fares are applicable to the accompanying passengers only in case the Club member is a **traveller in the booking**

As I understand you are part of the booking. It's not necessary to board the flight to use the discount for the other passenger of the booking.